# Binding a image upload to a bson.Binary object

Tags: angular, typescript, mongodb, bson

I've got a Java spring boot back-end which stores data in a mongodb. Via the Rest API I'll get this image-data and display the image in my Angular front-end.
Now, I want to make the POST-request , file uploading etc is working and i'll can get the base64-data.

In this code the binary-data is already available in the formData-property. The model class of the object to serialize is in the code below.

Whenever I post the data it's in the following format(img, nested from session -> sessionPhoto -> image). How would one serialize the image.data (base64 string) into the Binary object?

```
 onSubmit(sessionForm : NgForm) {;
    this.speakers = this.speakersControl.value;
    this.formData.speakers = this.speakers;
    let dateString = this.datePipe.transform(this.formData.session_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    console.log(this.formData);
    
    var result = this.sessionService.postSession(this.formData).subscribe(
      (res) => console.log(res),
      (err) => console.log(err),
      () => sessionForm.resetForm()
    );
  }
```

```
@Document("photo")
public class Photo {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String title;

    private Binary image;

    public Photo(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Binary getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Binary image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue.

Created a wrapper-image object to hold the returned data from the front-end and made a different setter for JSON-responses.

```
@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter
    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = new Binary(BsonBinarySubType.BINARY, Base64.getDecoder().decode(image.data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    }

    public void setImage(Binary binary){
        this.image= binary;
    }
```